# How to change default state of checkbox hack on diffrent screen size?

Tags: css, label, media

is it possible to have different state of check-box (input type....checked) on different screen size(@media screen and min-width...) I want my check-box hack to be open on big screen's and closed on small. How should css look like for this? (please, no JS solutions.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do...

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
input[type="checkbox"] {....} 
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 980px) { .home-search { 
input[type="checkbox"] {....} 
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { .home-search { 
input[type="checkbox"] {....} 
}
```

Hope this helps.......